# toggle sort order using anchor element.

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

i want to make a link toggle the sort order. i am using variable $order for the purpose. when i click once the link the href should be "?order=desc" then again when i click it should be "?order=asc". hoping for help.

```
if ( isset($_GET['order'])) { $order == $_GET['order']; } 
else { $_GET['order']=='asc'; }

$order = $_GET['order'];


<a href="?<?php if ($order='desc'){echo 'order=asc';}else {echo 'order=desc';}?>">order </a>
```

hope some body here could help me out with the above code ?

Comment: You are confusing `==` and `=`. `==` only makes sense for comparing values, but you try to use it for asignments. That won't produce the result you want.

Comment: @Daedalus: he can't, being a new member with a reputation of currently only 4...

Comment: @arkascha Being able to accept an answer to a question is not a privilege that must be earned.

Comment: @Daedalus: oh, has that been changed? Before you had to have at least 10 or 20 points, if I remember correctly. Made sense in my eyes...

Comment: @arkascha [To vote up, yes](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up), not to accept, which is completely different.

Comment: @jinni, To accept an answer to a question(which awards not only the user who answered your question, but you), click the outlined checkmark under the down arrow.

Comment: i totally didnt know about the tick mark. tried up arrow. didnt work . i thought it was the "was this answer useful to you" thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like that:

```
$order = isset($_GET['order'])?$_GET['order']:'asc'; 

<a href="?order=<?php echo (($order=='desc')?'asc':'desc');?>">
```

Comment: oh exactly what i want thanks. btw it wasnt such a hard task hun ?

Comment: why do you not use the if (condition) { statement } format ? easier this way ?

Comment: You should assing a value of `$order` or `href` doesn't matter if condition is `true` or `false`. So that's the preferable way. Construction `$r = (condition)?value1:value2;` - reperesents an if statement which result is stored in `$r` variable